# Adding a polynomial term to a linear model

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

My model is

`lm(formula = medv ~ crim + indus + rm + dis + crim * indus)`

I have to add the polynomial term `rm*rm` of order 2 to the above model. How do we do this in R?

Answer (score 5):

Here's two options.

```
lm(formula = medv ~ crim + indus + poly(rm, 2, raw = TRUE) + dis + crim * indus)
lm(formula = medv ~ crim + indus + rm + dis + crim * indus + I(rm^2))
```

The first uses `poly(..., raw = TRUE)` where `raw = TRUE` ensures the coefficients can be intepreted as usual. The latter uses the **as is operator** `I(...)` which evaluates whats within it before using it in a the formula context. Note that `x^2` isn't translated into the normal polynomial in **R** within a formula context.